# Sorting an enumeration column whose value is stored as int in database

Tags: c#, enums

I have a column on an asp.net Gridview whose type is an enumeration. I display the description of the enum on the UI, and save the int value in the database. This is my enum definition

```
public enum ItemStatus : int
{
   [DescriptionAttribute("New Item")]
   New = 0,
   [DescriptionAttribute("Closed")]
   Closed = 1,
   [DescriptionAttribute("Not Assigned")]
   Unassigned = 2,
   [DescriptionAttribute("Assigned")]
   Assigned = 3
}
```

I save this `ItemStatus` as an Int in the database and users see the enum string value (like Not Assigned) on the UI. Users should be able to do a sorting (Asc,Desc) on this column in the Grid.

Since I save this as an int in the Database, after I "hydrate" the object, the `ItemStatus` column on the UI is not sorted alphabetically. Users expect this to be sorted alphabetically on the UI.

I cant think of a way to do that.I use  Asp.net and C#
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've got two options here:

1. Create a view that contains the Text value, and use that to populate the Grid. That way, you can sort on the text value, rather than attempting to sort on the numeric key value.
2. Pull back all your results, and sort in memory.

Beyond that, I can't really see any option you have. If you attempt to sort on the key column, it's always going to sort numerically - because that's the data in the column.

Comment: No Problem. Out of curiosity, which method did you use in the end?